# Node.js SSL client connection with wrong certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am trying to use the [TLS](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_port_host_options_callback) module to perform an SSL connection to a server which happens to provide a wrong certificate (the hostname of server (xxx.example.com) does not match the common name of the certificate (yyy.example.com)).

I managed to get the client connecting without throwing an error by adding the option `rejectUnauthorized: false`.

However when the client is connected it is still [unauthorized](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_cleartextstream_authorized) and the [authorizationError](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_cleartextstream_authorizationerror) is **Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames**.

How can I get around this? I obviously have no power on changing the server certificate (I did however contact them to try to get them amend the certificate).

Comment: If you can't change the hostname in the certificate, can you change the hostname you're accessing the page through to the one in the certificate?

Comment: I thought about that but unfortunately the hostname in the certificate actually refers to another IP, so I cannot use it instead.

Comment: I can't see any way to do what you're asking in the official docs. Note that ignoring the hostname in the certificate verification makes SSL/TLS totally insecure, so may not be an option they felt was needed.

Comment: @quentinadam, you are deadlock condition, you can't either change the hostname in the certificate or don't have the IP server access referring the hostname.

Comment: @quentinadam if you have access of hostname/domain then you simply change the IP which is pointing to your hostname/domain with yours IP.